# using "$query" instead of $query

Tags: php, mysql

`mysql_query($query)` does not work

`mysql_error()` shows Query was empty

`mysql_query("$query")` works

What could be the probable reason?

```
$query = "
SELECT 
    field1a, 
    field1b, 
    field1c
FROM 
( 
    {$obj1->p1->p2['sub']}.table1
) 
LEFT JOIN 
    {$obj1->p1->p2['sub']}.table2
    ON 
    (
        field2a = field1d 
    ) 
WHERE 
    field1e = '$variable' ";
```

This is what i get when i echo the variable $query... just before passing to mysql_query

```
SELECT 
    field1a, 
    field1b, 
    field1c
FROM 
( 
    db.table1
) 
LEFT JOIN 
    db.table2
    ON 
    (
        field2a = field1d 
    ) 
WHERE 
    field1e = 'data' ";
```

The variable $query holds the same data even after executing the function call

I have enabled and checked mysql logs where i find the query data to be empty in the first case and ...

The query data is present in the second case when i used mysql_query("$query)

Comment: Can you please post the query you're testing with?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this context?

Comment: from my point of view and with no source code ... seems impossible!

Comment: Why are you using mysql instead of mysqli? http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php ift has better security and other features.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your $query is an empty variable.

so when you:

```
mysql_query($query)
```

You're basically doing mysql_query(); and gives an error.

when you do

```
mysql_error();
```

It even says it was empty because it's an empty var.

and when you do:

```
mysql_query("$query");
```

You just give an empty string to the function and yes it works because it is correct syntax.

Comment: i have verified the mysql query log ... and the query data is getting to the mysql server in the second case

Comment: Can you do a print_r($query); and post the result ?

Comment: modified my question including the query data